# What html/CSS/JS technology widgets does pagii.com use?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am interested in creating a web page editor like the one used in pagii.com? It's unique among the web based editors I have seen in that it offers a great deal of customization. For example you can insert an image and drag it anywhere on the screen and resize it on the fly. The elements can be placed anywhere on the screen and layered in a wysiwyg fashion. Initially I thought it was Flash based but it's not.

Are there CSS/Javascript libraries which provide similar capabilities? I mean a complete framework and not just stuff as in some Jquery plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are using any well-known frameworks/technolgies, [Wappalyzer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10229) should tell you what they are.

Answer (score 0):

I think [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) is the closest to what you are looking for (it has the [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)/[Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/)/[Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/) classes).

That said, it appears that pagii have written the page editor by themselves - at least my Firebug inspection got me to think this way.

Comment: Yeah, there is a pile of JavaScript on that page but it all looks very custom... I could not find any references to the scripts on google.